# program stopped working on switch statement C language

Tags: c, crash, switch-statement

I am writing a program for a class (C LANGUAGE) which would be a menu for an APP store. at some point in the program, the user will not have enough money to buy anything from the menu, so he will need to add money to his account, this is my function definition for that part below. as i run my program, it compiles and everything works until it reaches the switch statement below, then the program crashes but not with a run-time error, it says that "it has stopped working". this has never happened to me before, I have attached a screenshot of the error message. Please help, thank you.

```
void moneyChoice(double *depositPtr, double appCost)
{
int choice = 0;
printf("\n\nPlease credit your money by selection:\
           \n1 --   $15.00\
           \n2 --   $10.00\
           \n3 --   $5.00\
           \n4 --   $2.00\
           \n5 --   $1.00");
    printf("\nDeposit amount: ");
    scanf("%d", choice);

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        *depositPtr += 15.00;
        break;
    case 2:
        *depositPtr += 10.00;
        break;
    case 3:
        *depositPtr += 5.00;
        break;
    case 4:
        *depositPtr += 2.00;
        break;
    case 5:
        *depositPtr += 1.00;
        break;
    }
```

[image: screenshot of program crashing]}

Comment: Have you tried actually debugging the program?

Comment: scanf("%d", choice); --> no address? wassnt it &choice? Its writing to address zero which could be compilers first area or something like OS uses ?.

Comment: the variable is double deposit = 0; and in this function i am required to use a pointer by my professor which is why i'm using *depositPtr as the argument. the website is not letting me post the picture because it says i need a reputation score of ten....

Comment: Thank you so much huseyin tugrul buyukisik!!!! i was going crazy going over this code and hadn't noticed i was missing the &. thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use a valid address for scanf, such as  &choice.

```
 scanf("%d", &choice);
```

This uses choice's address to write the scanned values. When you write  scanf("%d", choice); it just gets zero(initial value of choice) as address and leads undefined behavior.

Scanf needs an address because it is altering its value inside the function. Address shows where the altering is needed(the address of choice's value). Similar way as you alter depositPtr 's pointed data.